# How to set a "Custom" sensitivity label?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to set the mail item "Custom" sensitivity label.

I looked at: [OlSensitivity enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsensitivity), which showed the standard 4 label values, like: `Outmail.Sensitivity = OlSensitivity.olConfidential` for the confidential label.

In my case, there are more than 5 labels -> sensitivity option with custom label name. How can I retrieve it based on custom label name in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar kind of issue where the company have their own Sensitivity Labels. We can't select with them with default numbering.

I came up with the solution by using the SendKeys in VBA.

The trick is not to use the `.Send`, instead use `.Display`. So once you have display of the draft email then see the keyboard hits to reach out to the custom Sensitivity.
As I am working in MS Office 365, the keyboard shortcuts to select my Custom sensitivity is below:

```
SendKeys "%h"           'Keystroke for ALT + h 
SendKeys "y"            'Keystroke for selecting the Sensitivity
SendKeys "{TAB}{ENTER}%s"      'Keystroke for selecting the organization custom sensitivity and %s is for ALT + s to send the email
```

Sample code

```
With objMail
    .To = strEmail
    .Body = strBody
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Display
SendKeys "%h"
SendKeys "y"
SendKeys "{TAB}{ENTER}%s"

End With
```

Also check the different codes for SendKeys from the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys