# How can I set Sensitivity or custom Sensitivity in an email?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need to send emails with a confidential tag.

Our in-house custom tag is "Patient-Confidential", there is no "Confidential" under "Sensitivity" but "Patient-Confidential" is the 3rd item on the "Confidential" drop-down list.

The default Outlook tag for confidential is .Sensitivity=3, but it doesn't change the sensitivity.

How can I assign sensitivity, either MS Outlook "Confidential" or "Patient-Confidential"?

I successively tried the following variations:

```vb
With OutMail
    .To = recipient
    .Subject = strsubject
    .Body = strbody
    .Sensitivity = "Patient-Confidential"
    .Sensitivity = 3
    .oLSensitivity = 3
    .oLSensitivity = "Patient-Confidential"
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: [How to set a "Custom" sensitivity label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630740/how-to-set-a-custom-sensitivity-label)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
With OutMail
.To = recipient
.Subject = strsubject
.Body = strbody
.Sensitivity = OlSensitivity.olConfidential
.Display
End With
```

The [MailItem.Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sensitivity) property returns or sets a constant in the [OlSensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsensitivity) enumeration indicating the sensitivity for the Outlook item.

Comment: I appreciate that idea, but the sensitivity is not changed.

Comment: How do you check whether sensitivity is set or not?

Comment: I looked at the sensitivity in the drafted email that was "displayed". I also sent an email to a coworker after it was displayed and it arrived as Business-General.

Comment: Did you try to call the `Save` method after setting the sensitivity property?

Comment: @BReal Perhaps write a routine that selects an email from your own InBox, and then check the value of the `.Sensitivity` property. Since the levels you quote don’t match the default ones (as linked in the answer above) it could be that a different policy has been applied to your system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-sensitivity-labels

Comment: A workaround solution could be to use a mail template. Create a blank template email in Outlook, on which you have manually set the sensitivity to “Patient Confidential”. Then create your new email in VBA using this as the template.